# How to write boolean comparsion function in Coq

Tags: boolean, compare, coq

I'm trying to remove all integers that are greater than 7 from a list as follows

```
filter (fun n => n > 7).
```

However I get the following error

```
The term "n > 7" has type "Prop" while it is expected to have type "bool".
```

I am new to Coq, how can I fix it?

Comment: The answer below is correct, and already in the standard library. Use the function `ltb` (less than boolean) from the standard library instead.  It has a defined notation `<?` .  Try this: `Require Import Nat List. Check filter (fun n => 7 <? n).`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `@List.filter nat` expects a function of type `nat -> bool` but you supplied a function of type `nat -> Prop`. Here, `@List.filter nat` is `List.filter` applied to the type argument `nat`. One difference between `bool` and `Prop` is that `bool` is decidable while `Prop` is not: there are propositions `P` such that neither `P` nor `~P` are known; one can always determine whether something is `true` or `false`.

In order to resolve this situation, you need to write a function of type `nat -> bool` that returns `true` when applied to an argument greater than `7` and `false` otherwise. You can take advantage of the fact that [the standard library defines boolean comparison functions](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Nat.html) over the natural numbers. I would also suggest reading the first volume of [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/index.html) to familiarize yourself with Coq. It is more accessible and easy-going than some other prominent introductions (it was used in a program verification course at my university that presupposed little functional programming experience).

Here is a minimal example using only the builtin list type and notations:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations. 

Fixpoint filterb {A : Type} (f : A -> bool) (xs : list A) : list A :=
  match xs with
  | []      => []
  | x :: xs => if f x then x :: filterb f xs else filterb f xs
  end. 

Fixpoint ltb (n m : nat) : bool :=
  match n, m with
  | n  , 0   => false
  | 0  , S m => true
  | S n, S m => ltb n m
  end.

Eval compute in (filterb (fun n => ltb 7 n) [5;6;7;8;9]).
(* = [8;9] *)
```